# add bootstrap size classes to body

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd need to add classes (according to bootstrap sm,md,lg,xl sizes) to the body tag. Is there a more fluent way of doing this?

```
function body_classes(){
            var current_width = $(window).width();
            if(current_width < 750)
            $('body').addClass("body-xs").removeClass("body-sm").removeClass("body-md").removeClass("body-lg").removeClass("body-xl");
            else if(current_width < 970)
            $('body').addClass("body-sm").removeClass("body-xs").removeClass("body-md").removeClass("body-lg").removeClass("body-xl");
            else if(current_width < 1170)
            $('body').addClass("body-md").removeClass("body-xs").removeClass("body-sm").removeClass("body-lg").removeClass("body-xl");      else if(current_width < 1450)
            $('body').addClass("body-lg").removeClass("body-xs").removeClass("body-sm").removeClass("body-md").removeClass("body-xl");    else 
            $('body').addClass("body-xl").removeClass("body-xs").removeClass("body-sm").removeClass("body-md").removeClass("body-lg");
        }

         body_classes();

        window.onresize = function(event) {
         body_classes();
        };
```

Comment: eeh? those classes don't exist in Bootstrap! Also, you don't need this at all since the whole concept of Bootstrap is for you NOT TO DO what you want to do! Is there any special reason for which you're doing this?

Comment: You probably forgot to add the bootstrap js files to your page.

Comment: Make sure you write this code after jQuery loaded, for me it does work, some improvements: you may use `.removeClass("body-sm body-md body-lg body-xl")` and cache the body `var $body = $('body');`

Comment: Basically I just want to do quick device specific hacks/details in css. Like a font sizes etc. I'm not using this to change the basic logic of bootstrap. Its just a body class like for example .ie8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQueryUI has a method called `switchClass` that would probably work better. Also, you can remove multiple classes within the `switchClass` method using space as the delimiter:

```
function body_classes() {

    var current_width = $(window).width();

    if (current_width < 750) {
        $('body').switchClass("body-sm body-md body-lg body-xl", "body-xs"); 
    } else if (current_width < 970) {
        $('body').switchClass("body-xs body-md body-lg body-xl", "body-sm");
    } else if (current_width < 1170) {
        $('body').switchClass("body-xs body-sm body-lg body-xl", "body-md");  
    } else if (current_width < 1450) {
        $('body').switchClass("body-xs body-sm body-md body-xl", "body-lg");   
    } else { 
        $('body').switchClass("body-xs body-sm body-md body-lg", "body-xl")
    }

};

body_classes();

window.onresize = function(event) {
    body_classes();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function body_classes() {

var current_width = $(window).width();

if (current_width < 480) {
    $('body').removeClass( 'body-sm body-md body-lg body-xl' );
    $('body').addClass( 'body-xs' );
} else if (current_width < 768) {
  $('body').removeClass( 'body-sm body-md body-lg body-xl' );
    $('body').addClass( 'body-sm' );
} else if (current_width < 992) {
    $('body').removeClass( 'body-sm body-md body-lg body-xl' );
    $('body').addClass( 'body-md' );
} else if (current_width < 1200) {
    $('body').removeClass( 'body-sm body-md body-lg body-xl' );
    $('body').addClass( 'body-lg' );   
} else if (current_width < 1450) {
    $('body').removeClass( 'body-sm body-md body-lg body-xl' );
    $('body').addClass( 'body-xl' );
}
```

};